# ASP.NET Session/Cache + multi-core processor server

Tags: asp.net, caching, session-state

I have a multi-core server hosting my asp.net solution.  In the past with dual-core, etc. you had to modify your app to NOT use in-proc session state, etc. Is this still the case if its a dual core?

Also, does server cache play a part in this?  I have had no issues with session, but when i try to clear the cache from code, it does not work, i have to do an iis reset to clear the cache. -- however, it does work locallay (i have a duo core) but not on the server (intel pentium D)

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In Process != In Processor.

You should have no problem (except for the ones that session brings) using the in process model on a multi proc machine, because the process (aspnet_wp.exe or w3wp.exe) is able to execute on any or all of the processors.

[The Http Cache?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache_members.aspx) should have items added and removed by key value.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use an out of process cache client such as microsofts velocity which can handle both cache and session out of process.  This will also scale out if you end up with more than one server.